# Where to ask for object / formation / effect identification

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, site-recommendation

This came into my mind when I was viewing Google satellite maps and noticed some interesting formation of objects somewhere in the middle of a lake.  I'd like to find out more about it, but since I don't know *what* it is, I can't even decide where (be it SE or elsewhere) to start.

Is it a geographical formation? Is it an animal or group of ones?  Is it a photographic noise?  Is it a result of a human activity (e.g. a land art)?

Other example could be an arbitrary detail of some photo.  I mean, if you found a picture on a Wikipedia page about a-bombs, topic of your choice would be military or physics, what you want to ask about something pictured in the background that is *not related* to tha main object?

I believe such question would be perfect for Q/A format.  Do we have a good place to start?

Comment: Skeptics SE maybe?  I'd suggest getting in their chat room and asking them if such a question would fit.